# access and read the external disk mounted on a server

Tags: command-line, server

How can I access and read and write files onto an external disk mounted on a server from my own ubuntu terminal?

Comment: How does the server offer access? SSH, FTP, Samba, NFS...?

Comment: @Jos it is SSH , could you give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sshfs` for this.

1. install it by running `sudo apt-get install sshfs`
2. run `sshfs user@server:/path/to/dir /path/to/mountpoint/` with your actual paths
3. access the data by `cd /path/to/mountpoint/`. You can use the data from the server the same way as a hard-drive in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to connect to a SSH server in order to view its files is to open `nautilus` (a.k.a. Files), press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>and type `ssh://username@servername`. You will be asked for a password. The other side needs to support and permit this, but Ubuntu does this out of the box.